# Actions on google - account linking

Tags: oauth, actions-on-google, google-account

My problem with linking the account is that I don't know which of my "request contains an invalid argument" when it comes to testing my google assistant.  It is for sure a problem with account linking.

My setup is:

- Grant type: authorization code
- Client-ID: client-id from google project -> oauth
- Client secret: client-secret from google project -> oauth
- Authorization url: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth
- Token url: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token
- scopes: email
- add quick account link is checked
- auto google sign-in is checked
- gsi client id: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth
- testing instructions is formated as follows (username first line, password second line):

> username-mail@gmail.com
>
> passwordasplaintext

This is my configuration. I have no idea what's wrong with it.. The client id and client secret are for sure correct. Any suggestions what might cause that I'm not able to link the account?

Thanks!

Comment: Not clear on what you are trying to do and what error if any you are getting. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: It isn't clear at which step you're getting this error. Can you send a sample OAuth handshake that shows what you're getting and sending?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While there may be other problems (it is difficult to tell), at least part of the problem is that the *GSI Client ID*... isn't a Client ID. It shouldn't be a URL, but should be the Client ID you make on the Credentials page of your Google API Console (not the Actions Console).

To make that Client ID:

1. Go to the [Credentials](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials) page for your project.
2. Click the `Create Credentials` button.
3. Select `OAuth Client ID`.

[image: screen shot of Create Credentials -> OAuth Client ID]

4. Select `Web Application`.
5. Enter a name
6. You can skip the *Authorized JavaScript Origin*, but set the *Authorized Redirect URI* to the OAuth redirect URL, which should be in the form `https://oauth-redirect.googleusercontent.com/r/your-project-id-000000` (replacing your project ID)
7. Click `Create`

[image: Web Application dialog screen shot]

8. On the Credentials page, you will see a list of *OAuth 2.0 Client IDs*. You'll want to get the *Client ID* from this table and use this in the *GSI Client ID* field.

[image: OAuth 2.0 Client ID table]